# Problem When connected through RDP to XRDP in ubuntu current windows open arent show

Tags: xrdp

When I remote access into my computer through RDP using XRDP on my Linux machine,I cannot see the last opened windows that I left when I login through other computer to my home computer. Instead it just gives me a fresh starting desktop with none of my previous Windows and app running. For example, if I had Firefox open, when I remote login I can't see the Firefox window open.

Where is my open windows and running apps?
Anyone run into this? Or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at this location (http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=4168), this post explains how you could configure you xrdp to try to reconnect to existing session

I hope that this would help you

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.. to get it working for me I edited my `xrdp.ini` by runing

```
sudo gedit /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
```

then added the below to the list for my set up:

```
[xrdp8] 
name=Reconnect 
lib=libvnc.so 
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1 
port=5910
```

I first log in to my machine usung the default `sesman-Xvnc` connection option in the 'Login to xrdp' 'Module' drop-down list..

This creates the original session that i can then log back into later by selecting the `Reconnect` option i have created which should now show in the 'Login to xrdp' 'Module' drop-down.

All my open programs, windows and files are just as i left them in the first session when i log back in using this..

I can then access this same session again from any of my other Windows PC's Remote Desktop Connection clients by again selecting `Reconnect` in the Xrdp login 'Module' drop-down.